# Catch Disk out of space exception in SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, smo, diskspace

We are taking db backups programatically by using `SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup` class. It is working perfectly.

Now i want to catch the "Disk out of space exception" separately. When we are trying to save a backup of large size may be greater than free available size, i got this exception in the general catch block.

But i need to catch this exception separately. I have tried with SmoException also. But can't find any useful exception category. Give your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried FailedOperationException ?

Comment: @Tanveer-lbn-Haresh: yes.. But i think the FailedOperationException is not specific to "disk out of space exception"

Comment: I do expect an exception-type, specifically for every error event, but failedoperationexception should help you to catch any public smo operation.

Comment: @Tanveer-lbn-Haresh: But i just want to get the "disk out of space exception" separately because i want to notify the user about the disk space issue only. If something like invalid path etc also come under this FailedOpertionException and i don't want to catch this.

Comment: If you just want to show a message to the user, did you look at the inner exception message that comes up, you could do a contain lookup for specific word or collection of word, to be sure about the error and then raise your message.

Comment: @Tanveer-lbn-Haresh: yes.. now we have done it. But i think its not a good method. If we get any specific error code for this type of exception then i think it will be great..

Comment: As long as you are not using your language and compiler, you can't expect everything to be your way, that's the world we live in.